# i want to edit an image file in the view page itself dont want to go to edit page

Tags: php, mysql

I am just a beginner so don't know how to exactly merge a view program and edit program. 
when I press my edit 'button' it goes to upload page but I don't want any interface page between view page and edit process

**view.php**

this is my view page

```
<a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>" style="float:left; height: 10em; margin-left:15px; margin-bottom: 2em" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you wish to edit this item?')">edit</a>
<a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>" style="float:left; height: 10em; margin-left:15px; margin-bottom: 2em"  onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this item?')">delete</a>
```

this is my edit page

**edit.php**

```
 <html>
    <body>
        <?php
            include "conntn2.php";
            $sql="select * from pictures where id='$id'";
            $res=mysqli_query($conkey,$sql);
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
            {
                ?>
        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="file" name="image" value="<?php echo $row['image'];?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="sub" value="submit"></td>
            </tr>
        </form>
        <?php
            }
            ?>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['sub'])) {
        include "conntn2.php";
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
        $id   = $_REQUEST['q'];
        $file = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
        $res1 = "update pictures set image='$file' where id='$id'";
        if (mysqli_query($conkey, $res1)) {
            header("location:cari1.php");
        }
    }
    ?>
```

I want to edit the file directly from view page. 
Please someone help me.

Comment: Please specify "*i dont want any interface page between view page and edit process*" in relation to the result you currently get.

Comment: in the output when i click the edit the link leads to edit.php page there the edit process happens and redirect to view page       what i need is when i click the edit button i dont want to go to another page

Comment: Please add the Javascript code for the `confirm('Are you sure you wish to XXX this item?')` implementation.

Comment: fyi, your HTML table is missing opening and closing `<table>` tags

Answer (score 0):

Include your edit.php code in the same file view.php and use query to show it up.
initially your edit code display is none. when the user presses the edit button use jquery to show the edit code and hide the view code.
In this way you dont have to redirect user to another page.